# Why would a node stop updating chain?

Tags: private-blockchain, synchronization

I am running a private network and one node seems to have stopped updating its chain. It is stuck at block 264 while the others are hundreds past it. It is still connected to the network, but it has stopped logging altogether. I can still interact with it from the console.

Comment: Check the connected peers from geth's console `admin.peers`. Check the log message, if there's any error it should there. Check for hardware errors, like not enough RAM memory, disk space or data corruption.

Comment: The node still lists the peers it should be connected to. The only log message out of the ordinary I see is `WARN: Synchronisation failed, dropping peer` with the associated error `"no peers available or all tried for download"`